# Stream Video to android camera like virtual webcam - Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio

Is there any way to stream **pre-recorded** video as a **virtual webcam** and then, if we open the camera, it'll show the video we set as virtual camera as hardware front camera in Java of Android Studio?